# Is there a way to differentiate left/right mouse clicks in iPhone Simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

For testing it would be great if I could differentiate clicking in the iPhone Simulator between left/right mouse buttons.  Or alternatively using the keyboard to generate these clicks.  Anyone done this before?  Either through code or an external tool?

Comment: I'm not sure what that would accomplish: You can't right-click or left-click on the iPhone, so why would you want to do it on the iPhone simulator?

Comment: It would make it easier to test in the simulator for my app.  This would not be put into production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no visible way to implement this type of action in the simulator

Answer (score 6):

Only different type of touch that you can get in the iOS Simulator are 2-finger gestures. While holding alt, you get 2 circles which represent 2 fingers. When you move the move, you perform rotating gesture. If you want to move those 2 "fingers", hold shift too.

Comment: Yep.  Definitely some other gestures to work with.  Won't help me for my current situation unfortunately.  Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: What exactly is your situation? I don't really see the point of testing something in simulator that can't be done on real device.

Comment: I have some parts of my app where clicking on one half of the screen does action #1, clicking on the other half does action #2.  If I didn't have to move the mouse for these separate clicks it would save me some time.  Yes I could separately click on either side of the screen but again that mouse movement to get those two clicks is what I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: When this is an action I have to many many times a day yes I want to be as lazy as possible.  The lazier the better.

Comment: "why not deploy it on device and tap each button with one finger? I really don't see your point."  2 > 1.  I'm always on the lookout for ways to optimize my time.  That's all I'm trying to do here.  Won't kill me to not get a solution but was curious if anyone had encountered this type of thing before.

Answer (score 3):

You can't right click on the device... so what would the point be of attempting to recreate this in the simulator?

Comment: See my response to @fichek above.  This would be purely to make testing easier.